# Same use case, different actors, slightly different scenarios

Tags: uml, use-case

Let's say I have a use case named "addSalesForecast" and I have two actors : the shop manager and the CEO 
Well the shop manager can only add sales forecasts for his own shop on the other hand the CEO can add sales forecasts for all the shops. So the difference would be that the CEO will have to select a shop first then add the forecast (the shop manager will have direct access to add the forecast).
I thought that I can solve this by adding an "If" in the scenario for example : "if the user is the CEO then he will have to select a shop first".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `<<extend>>` relation is often used wrong and you should simply not use it. Instead you just apply pre- and post-conditions which express the need to first select the shop:

[image]

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243605/what-is-the-best-way-to-structure-these-use-cases).